# How to print my methods name

Tags: c#, .net

I am new on coding just need find out if it is possible to get methods name and print using console.write. Here I have sample class and I want to grab "myName" so I can use it to print.

```
using System;

namespace Tests
{
    class Class1
    {
        public void myName()
        {
            Console.Write(myName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get like this for full information:

```
string method = string.Format("{0}.{1}", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
```

And return this string. Using call this within the metod.
Or short version just for name method, what you want:

```
string method =System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

Comment: Try this method `public void neiiic()
        {
            var names = Enumerable.Range(0, 15).Select(i => System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "" + i).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, names));
        }`

Comment: Thank you quick replay, How about when I need call outside the method, let say I have another method2 and I want to call method1 name inside mthod2, is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the [nameof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) keyword

```
Console.Write(nameof(myName));
```